# Declaring protected function friend

Tags: c++, function, friend, protected

Does `A::foo` need to be declared public for `B` to declare it friend?

```
class A {
    protected:  // public ?
        void foo(int x);
};

class B : public A {
    friend void A::foo(int);  // not fine with GCC 4.8.1 but fine with VS 2013
    void goo(int x) {foo(x);}  // fine
    static void hoo(int x) {}
};

void A::foo(int x) {B::hoo(x);}  // friend declaration needed for this
```

Visual Studio 2013 thinks it is fine if A::foo is protected, but GCC 4.8.1 thinks it's not and wants it to be public.  Which compiler is correct?  My initial instinct was that it can be declared protected.  After all, B is derived from A, so should have access to A::foo (as B::goo demonstrates trivially).

Comment: If it's public, there's no point in making it a friend. If it's protected, there's still no point in your example because you inherit from `A`, and can thus access all its protected members anyway.

Comment: @Cameron.  I've edited the post to show that the friend declaration is needed.

Comment: Asked on iso-discussion https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/f48xp0QcHJk

Comment: Other than the question being interesting from a language lawyer perspective, do you think that is a *good* design? The base *knowing* about the derived type? That seems a bit off... you have a cyclic dependency in your design. Even if there is a way to make the compiler digest that code, your design is at the very least doubtful.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Nikos Athanasiou Got this right! VS is right. Funny thing, Clang also got this wrong, but fortunately there's a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19686) for it to clear things up.

Comment: A base class knowing about child classes seems downright wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**VS is correct here**.

The name `A::foo` is in fact accessible in the scope of `B` since it's publicly derived from `A`. To [**prove**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e8babae9d8a6aab) this, consider

```
class A {
    protected:
        void foo(int x);
};

class B : A {
    using A::foo; // it's OK to refer to the name A::foo
};

void A::foo(int x) {}
```

So by using the quote § 11.3 [friend functions]

> A name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the scope of the class containing the friend declaration.

we can argue that's there's no violation of the rules (`foo` is also protected in the derived class).

<sup>It seems like in gcc, once the `friend` keyword is placed in front of the friend function declaration, name lookup starts ignoring inheritance (nothing to do though with friendship not being inheritable)</sup>

---

As mentioned by [40two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2352671/40two) in the comments **the same error is emitted from Clang and there's a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19686) for it**; this issue is also reffered to [DR209](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#209). It seems that for the implementers to get this right is quite hard.

Comment: +1 you're right, the same error is emitted from [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8caf1e0b9f99692). There's a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19686) for it. I searched bugzilla for GCC a bug report but I didn't find anything specific. Also this issue is reffered to [DR209](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#209). It seems that for the implementers to get this right is quite hard. P.S feel free to use any of the info here to improve you answer ;)

Comment: @40two Thnx for 40fying the answer

Comment: So it seems that the previous unanimous answer has changed.  Looks like we've all learned something from this.

Comment: @prestokeys I had this answer from the beginning (that's why originally I began my answer with "I have to disagree"); after the other answers were deleted I had to change that. Judging from the upvotes, I'd say that not many people were impressed, so I'd have to suppose this was not a novelty for the community as well.

Comment: @prestokeys Thanks to Nikos I certainly learned something from this ;). However, situations like this happen a lot to this type of questions. After all this is the major advantage between religion and science (i.e., Science doesn't have a dogma and you can arguable shout I was wrong! without many consequences).